# Extending/re-applying a function's 'try/except' error checking to its sub-functions?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that downloads and/or updates files via GitHub based on their age. I broke it into two functions:

1. *update_data()*, which handles logic tied to checking whether the local file exists and if so, determines the local file's "age" by grabbing the remote file's last-modified date and comparing it against the local file.
2. *download_file()*, which is called INSIDE of *update_data()*, it hosts the logic of  downloading the actual file

BOTH functions use *requests.get()* to download something and it can raise a *ConnectionError* if there's something wrong with the Internet connection at the time of download.

**Here's the issue:** I tried including the try/except logic only in *update_data()*, thinking that since *download_file()* is inside it, then if a *ConnectionError* is raised inside download_file() then surely that will be taken care of. Apparently I'm wrong, and *download_file()* ignores the try/except error checking of whatever function it's in. Is there a way to make the *download_file()* function follow the try/except rules of the function it's nested in? And if not, how else should I handle what I'm trying to do in a clean and concise way?

Here's a snippet of *update_data()*. I'm not including what's in *download_file()* since all that matters is it lacks the try/except part that this function does have.

```
for file_name, remote_path in file_paths.items():
    while True:
        try:
            local_file_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_name))
            api_url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/owid/covid-19-data/commits?path={remote_path}&per_page=1"
            last_updated = requests.get(api_url).json()[0]['commit']['committer']['date']
            remote_file_date = datetime.strptime(last_updated, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            delta = (remote_file_date - local_file_date).days
            if delta >= 0:
                choice = input(f"{file_name} is OUTDATED. It's roughly {str(delta + 1)} days old. "
                               "Would you like to update it? (Y/N): ")
                if "y" in choice.lower():
                    download_file(file_name, remote_path)
            break
        except ConnectionError:
            print("CAN'T CONNECT TO THE INTERNET! Your files might be out of date."
                  "Try checking your internet connection or Github's status.")
            return
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "download_data() ignores the try/except error checking of whatever function it's in"?

Comment: Is `download_file` in your code snippet what you're referring to as _download_data_ in your explanation? If there are no try-except blocks in `download_file`, the error should be propagated upwards. Are you certain that the error that is propagated from `download_file` is of type ConnectionError? According to the doc of the requests library, there are other errors that could occur: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions

Comment: @wxker you're right, I was just using the wrong kind of error in the except block. Changing `ConnectionError` to `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` worked.